# Обьединить два массива в один, но с одним условием

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Здравствуйте , у меня такая вот задача:

есть два массивы, в этих массивах есть слова. Слова в этих массивах записаны в рандомном порядке. Нужно эти 2 массива объединить в один , так чтобы в новом массиве шли сначала слова которые имеют парное количество гласных букв, а потом все остальные слова.

Например: есть массив: `$str = 'лама, мама, конь'` И есть 2 массив `$str2 = 'клас, бабушка , клава'`. Нужно чтобы такой массив получился такой: (лама, мама, клава, конь, бабушка)

ЧТо я придумал:

```
<?php

$str = 'Mother,  Fther';
$strTwo = 'sister,  brother';


$result = str_split($str); 
$resultTwo = str_split($strTwo);



if(...) {

 $test = array_merge($result , $resultTwo);   
}


?>
```

Ка вообще реализовать такую задачу, что нужно использовать, какие методы, можно как то сделать без регулярок эту задачу?? Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем здесь применять регулярки - я не знаю, возможно "специалисты" и сделают. А мы обойдемся и без них. Вот к примеру так выглядит функция, которая подсчитывает кол-во гласных в слове:

```
function count_letter($x) {
    $c = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($x); $i++) {
        if (strpos('euoaiy', $x[$i]) > -1) {
            $c+=1;
        }
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Там конечно латинские буквы, но это дело житейское. Сам код построен просто - проходим по всем буквам слова и проверяем есть ли эта буква в специальном слове с одних гласных. Можно конечно было написать длинющий if и проверять каждую букву, но оставим это индусам и гореоптимизаторам.

Теперь сам алгоритм решения задачи. Пробегаем по каждому слову и если там четное кол-во гласных - пишем в массив четных, иначе - в массив для нечетных. Потом это же проделываем и со вторым массивом. И в самом конце эти два массива просто "складываем".

Как же проверить, что кол-во гласных четно? очень просто - с помощью взятия модуля - a % 2 будет равно 0, если число четно. А дальше самостоятельно:)

Comment: ойойоой. что то запутался я уже. я вообще нормально начал писать код свой?? и непонятно ваша фраза:  Пробегаем по каждому слову и если там парное кол-во гласных - пишем в первый массив, иначе - во второй. Потом это же проделываем и со вторым массивом. А что значит первый, второй? мне же нужно в один поместить массив

Comment: аа понял вы мне функцию как пример привели

Comment: @M-Misha-M: Доускает ли ваше условие такую пару: `tool` - две гласные подряд.

Comment: @romeo да допускает, главное чтобы было парное количество

Comment: @KoVadim я попробовал по вашему алгоритму, но что не вышло обьединить, гляните плз, просто для себя хочеться разобраться . http://pastebin.com/m8N4ewUW

Comment: там в коде было немного лишнего. К примеру, не совсем понятно, зачем массив нужно было объединять в одну строку (вызовом implode). Поправил баги и упростил код http://ideone.com/CVM8jG

Comment: То же самое делает "регулярка"   preg_replace("/[aeiouy]/i", "", $key, -1, $count);

Answer (score 1):

Если без использования 2-х массивов (мин. версия PHP 5.4.0), то функцию для получения количества гласных букв уже описали, дальше можно сделать так:

```
$words1 = ['Mother', 'Grandfather', 'Brother', 'Sister'];
$words2 = ['Uncle', 'Father', 'Grandmother'];

$words = [];

array_map(function ($word) use (&$words) {

    if (count_letter($word) % 2 === 0) { // если количество гласных букв - парное
        array_unshift($words, $word); // добавляем слово в начало массива
    } else {
        $words[] = $word;
    }

}, array_merge($words1, $words2));

print_r($words);
```

Comment: Только почему `array_splice()`, а не `array_unshift()`? И предупредите топикстартера, в каких версиях PHP это заработает.

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо, поправил на `array_unshift`

Comment: @JILeXanDR, спасибо вам большое, только непонятна эта строчка array_map(function ($word) use (&$words)

Comment: @M-Misha-M В PHP, в замыканиях отсутствует доступ в внешнему контексту, и передать нужные переменные можно с использованием ключевого слова `use`. А амперсанд говорит о том, что переменная будет передана по ссылке, иначе любые действия с ней будет совершены только локально.

Comment: Uncle обработается некорректно. Надо исправить strpos() на stripos()

Answer (score 1):

Можно рассуждать иначе.

1. С точки зрения конечного результата массивы неупорядочены, и последующая их сортировка неизбежна. Поэтому сразу сливаем их в один (функция array_merge().
2. Обмениваем местами ключи и значения общего массива (функция array_flip()).
3. Заменяем номер элемента на_массив, состоящий из этого номера и бита чётности от числа гласных в слове (функция array_walk()).
   Число гласных букв в слове подсчитывает *регистронезависимая* функция str_ireplace() с дополнительным параметром $count или её "регулярный аналог" (благодарность [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim)).
   Бит чётности - это(count & 1)
4. Сортируем функцией uasort() с учётом исходного порядка и бита чётности.
5. Готовый массив ключей 'отрезаем" функцией array_keys().

Программа:

```
$array1 = array("Father", "Mother", "Sister", "Grandfather");
$array2 = array("Grandmother", "Brother", "Aunt");

$array12= array_merge($array1, $array2);
var_dump($array12);

$flip = array_flip($array12);   
array_walk($flip, function(&$item,$key) {
    // str_ireplace(array("a","e","i","o","u","y"), "", $key, $count);
    preg_replace("/[aeiouy]/i", "", $key, -1, $count);
    $item = array($item, $count & 1);
});

uasort($flip, function($a,$b){
    if(end($a)==end($b))    return reset($a)-reset($b);
    else                    return end($a) - end($b);
});

$result = array_keys($flip);
var_dump($result);
```

Результаты (массив после слияния и готовый массив):

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'Father' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Mother' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Sister' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Grandfather' (length=11)
  4 => string 'Grandmother' (length=11)
  5 => string 'Brother' (length=7)
  6 => string 'Aunt' (length=4)
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'Father' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Mother' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Sister' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Brother' (length=7)
  4 => string 'Aunt' (length=4)
  5 => string 'Grandfather' (length=11)
  6 => string 'Grandmother' (length=11)
```