# php запись фрагмента строки в переменную

Tags: php

Имеется строка вида `текст1(текст2)`. Нужно чтобы `а = текст1`, `б = текст2`.
Проще говоря, нужно записать текст без скобок в одну переменную, а текст в скобках - в другую. Подскажите какую функцию использовать для подобного? Или тут только регулярные выражения?

UPD  В общем ответы на вопросы я получил, увидел примеры, и наверное все таки лучше сделаю через регулярные выражения. Т.к все ответы довольно интересные, правильный я выбрать все таки не могу. Спасибо!

Comment: Регулярками наиболее простое решение. А так, есть куча строковых функций по поиску и вырезанию. есть explode который разбивает строку по заданному символу (правда при этом закрывающаяся скобка останется во втором значении и ее надо будет вырезать. Можно sscanf по формату попробовать. Ну и просто strpos найти скобку, substr вырезать подстроку. А оно надо ? не надо бояться регулярок, они не особо сложны, тем более для таких простых случаев, зато эффективны

Comment: @Mike sscanf для строк не работает, explode по одной скобке - несолидно )

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Почему не солидно. В вашем варианте можно не менять скобку на <br> и получится как раз по скобке

Comment: @Mike да, так массивы громоздить не надо

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = 'first(second)';
$start =strpos($temp, '(');
$end = strpos($temp, ')');
$second =  substr($temp, $start, $end);
$first = str_replace($second, '', $temp);
list($first, $second) = [$first, $second];
echo $first .'</br>'. $second;
```

Comment: Там скобки в second останутся. start.end стоит подкорректировать при вырезании. и вместо replace то же substr, а то скобки в first останутся

Comment: да покоректировать то не проблема +-1 Дело в другом почему то код у меня не обрезает $second по $end

Comment: в общем почему то не видит $end

Comment: @Alex Ну да, это же позиции ... должно быть так `$second =  substr($temp, $start+1, $end-$start-1);`

Comment: выведет оно
текст1()
текст2

Comment: я подумал вам надо второе значение что бы было в скобках. Методов реализации очень много

Comment: Друзья как отрезать скобки?)

Comment: $temp = 'first(second)';
 $first = str_replace(['(', ')'], '|', $temp);
 list($first, $second) = explode('|', $first);
 echo $first .'</br>'. $second ;

Answer (score 1):

Можно так (с учётом замечания @Mike - покороче):

```
$s = str_replace(")", "", "текст1(текст2)");
$ars = explode("(", $s);    
print("a=$ars[0] b=$ars[1]");
```

Результат:

```
a=текст1 b=текст2
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с регулярным выражением здесь напрашивается сам собой:

```
preg_match('/^([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)$/', 'текст1(текст2)', $parts);
echo($parts[1]); // текст1
echo($parts[2]); // текст2
```

Варианты с ручным разбиванием текста, в данном случае - костыль.

Comment: Интересно, а здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462840/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/471749#471749 есть простор для регулярных выражений?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, для каждой задачи нужен свой инструмент. Здесь регулярные выржения - идеальный вариант. А в вопросе по ссылке лучше обойтись без них

Comment: Спасибо за квалифицированный совет. Мы все стремимся к идеалу, но каждый в силу своих возможностей.

Comment: Получилось с регуляркой и там, посмотрите )